# I want convert from string to date

Tags: xcode, string, date

```
NSDate *LastBuildDate;    
NSDate *PubDate;

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddhhmmss"];
LastBuildDate = [formatter dateFromString:buttoninfoamtion.mLastdate];
PubDate=[formatter dateFromString:newsItem.mPubDate];

   if([PubDate compare:LastBuildDate])
```

buttoninfomation.mlastdate and newsItem.mPubDate is string from OpenAPI

ex)
buttoninfomation.mlastdate: Tue, 18 Oct 2011 15:54:43 +0900
newspub:Tue, 18 Oct 2011 15:58:00 +0900

but
  LastBuidDate = (null)
PubDate = (null)

I want to compare two factor .

So date- date or string- string but I think string - string is so complex.

what wrong up codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the format you've given of "yyyyMMddhhmmss" doesn't match "Tue, 18 Oct 2011 15:54:43 +0900" even slightly.

Try

```
EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
```

as the format string - see the [iOS documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) and the Unix [TR#35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for more information.